# Include salt in dry premix?

Tags: baking, dough, salt, mixing

Should salt be part of the dry premix? I plan to start making dry premixes, as normally done in factory operations. Separated for different pastries, the premixes will include any of the ff: flour, baking soda, cornstarch, and cocoa powder. My question is, can salt be part of a premix, or should I reserve it for the wet mix on the day of dough-preparation?

Reason I ask is because the original recipe for cookies that I used, instructed to mix in salt with the dry ingredients. However, knowing that salt is a polar compound, I figured it might fare better by being homogenous with the eggs, butter, and sugar. On the other hand, by mixing salt with the dry ingredients, I know that it would already be set and I won't have to worry about forgetting to put salt in my batter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say, go ahead and include the salt with the dry ingredients. Polar or non-polar may be critical if you are in a chem lab, but in the kitchen this is my reasoning:

1) Most recipes I have seen for baked goods, call for mixing the salt with the dry ingredients.

2) I have never seen a commercial mix (biscuits, pancakes, cakes, muffins, etc.) that ever called for the baker to add salt to the mix, making me think that salt is included in the mix as purchased.

Maybe the polar/non-polar thing is less important than convenience.